# Auto updation of a field in table based on another field in the same table

Tags: javascript

I am developing a shopping cart. So far I have listed the products in one's cart. Each product has its name,price,quantity and subtotal.Quantity is given as drop down list. When the user changes the drop down list value, automatically the price has to change. This functionality uses ajax. I got the id of the particular drop down list. Now how can I use that id to change the price of particular product? Please help me

Comment: Please show your code so we can help. We dont write whole code for you here. Just help on yur research.

Answer (score 0):

something like this: [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/crustyashish/5QZkM/)

**HTML**

```
Price: <input type="text" id="price" value="100" /><br />

Quantity :
<select id="qty" onchange="calculate()">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
</select>
<br />
Total : <input type="text" id="total" /><br />
```

**JS**

```
<script>
function calculate()
    {
       var price = document.getElementById("price").value;
       var qty = document.getElementById("qty").value;
       var total = parseFloat(price) * parseFloat(qty);
       document.getElementById("total").value = total;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: But how can I display it in the row corresponding to the dropdownbox?.I have to display in the html.